# What is the purpose of godparents?

Tags: catholicism, godparents

I was looking through Catholic baptismal records, while doing genealogy, when I realized that I didn't know what the purpose of godparents is. What is their purpose? Why are they recorded? Are the godparents held accountable for anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good explanatation is given in ["The Role of Godparents" by Fr. William Saunders](http://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/view.cfm?id=1465&repos=1&subrepos=0&searchid=325759)

As per Code of Canon Law 872 - 874 the rules are as below:

> Can.872  Insofar as possible, a person to be baptized is to be given a
>   sponsor who assists an adult in Christian initiation or together with
>   the parents presents an infant for baptism. A sponsor also helps the
>   baptized person to lead a Christian life in keeping with baptism and
>   to fulfill faithfully the obligations inherent in it.
>
> Can.873  There is to be only one male sponsor or one female sponsor or one of each.
>
> Can.874  §1. To be permitted to take on the function of sponsor a
>   person must:
>
> 1. Be designated by the one to be baptized, by the parents or the person who takes their place, or in their absence by the pastor or
>      minister and have the aptitude and intention of fulfilling this
>      function;
> 2. Have completed the sixteenth year of age, unless the diocesan bishop has established another age, or the pastor or minister has
>      granted an exception for a just cause;
> 3. Be a Catholic who has been confirmed and has already received the most holy sacrament of the Eucharist and who leads a life of faith in
>      keeping with the function to be taken on;
> 4. Not be bound by any canonical penalty legitimately imposed or declared;
> 5. Not be the father or mother of the one to be baptized.

So the primary purpose is to take care of the *Catholic faith formation*, and it does not hold them accountable to taking care of the child in the future.

Answer (score -3):

In times of old, it was not uncommon for the parents of a child to die, leaving no relatives behind.  In such a case, who would get the child? Perhaps the church, if parents where part of it, or the child would be on its own. Thus, I think god parenting came out of need for the child. It is called compassion.